# Hide metadata in print method

Tags: r, printing

I want to print a `tibble` however it gives me additional information that is not wanted.

```
> print(as.tibble(head(mtcars)))
# A tibble: 6 × 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
3  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
4  21.4     6   258   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
5  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
6  18.1     6   225   105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
>
```

Specifically i don't want to show lines starting with #
How can i show the raw table instead?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the `AsIs` method of `print` to get the raw table.

```
> print.AsIs(as.tibble(head(mtcars)))
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```